# Работа с вызванной программой

Tags: golang

Необходимо с помощью Go производить автоматизацию процессов ввода информации в запущенную программу из консоли. Например возьмем программу ftp:

1. При появлении "ftp>" ввести следующие данные "open 192.168.0.1"
2. При появлении "Name (192.168.0.1):" ввести имя пользователя

Подскажите как это реализовать?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/absh", "-c", "ftp")

    pipe, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    pipe.Write([]byte("open 192.168.0.1"))
    pipe.Close()

    output, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(output))
}
```

Comment: Думаю надо использовать не только StdinPipe() но и StdoutPipe() и реагировать на ответы приложения

Comment: А какие ещё программы вы хотите автоматизировать?

Comment: Если этот вопрос кому-то актуален, то в Go есть реализация `expect`: https://github.com/google/goexpect